# looping over a string and checking against dictionary

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, dictionary

I have a file I am reading using a `StreamReader` this is then split into individual words that are to be checked against a `dictionary`. I am able to split the text up and loop through however, the loop does not end, it keeps looping and does not stop at the end of the file. see below code;

```
private void Load_File_Contents_BTN_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string FilePath = File_Path_TB.Text;

        //Implements Dictionary
        var fileParser = new FileParser(@"C:\textwords.csv");
        fileParser.Parse();

        //handles reading, splitting and searching of file
        FileStream inFile = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader(inFile);

        char[] stringSep = { ',', ' ', '!', '?', '.' };

        string[] isInFile = readFile.ReadToEnd().Split(stringSep);

        for (int i = 0; i < isInFile.Length; i++)
        {
            while (i < isInFile.Length)
            {
                foreach (string s in isInFile)
                {
                    if (fileParser.IsWordAvailable(s.ToString()))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Match found");
                        Console.WriteLine(s.ToString());// displays word checked in console
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("No match");
                        Console.WriteLine(s.ToString());// displays word checked in console
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I am unsure as to what I have missed here.

any insights would be greatly appreciated

Cheers,

Comment: You have an infinite loop inside your first `for` loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `while` loop is expecting to terminate when `i >= isInFile.Length` but `i` is never updated inside the `while` loop block. Infinite loop.

In fact, it would appear that you're trying to iterate over `isInFile` in three different ways: `for`, `while` and `foreach`. You probably only need the `foreach` loop.

Comment: of course, ive been looking at that for a half hourtrying to figure it out. cheers!